# How to print A6 book in ubuntu? (8-page imposition duplex)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pdf, printing

I want to print a book to bind it, but I can't print the correct sequence of pages.

There are 248 pages in this book.

I want to print it like this (duplex) but into 2 "segments" :

[image: 8-page imposition]

In this order from top to bottom, left to right:

1. first segment:
   1.1. first paper:
     front: 2,4,15,13
     back : 16,14,1,3

   1.2. second paper:
     front: 6,8,11,9
     back : 12,10,5,7
2. second segment: and so on...

I use one A4 paper and I fold it horizontally and vertically to a A6 format.

Is there a program or a scripts that can solve this problem for me for future printing?

At least a script to follow this sequence : 2,4,15,13,16,14,1,3,6,8,11,9,12,10,5,7,18,20,31,29,32,30,17,19,22,24,27,25,28,26,21,23...

And thanks for any help.

Comment: Just a note here: if you're printing this duplex, only one dimension of folding would make sense... the other dimension would want to be cut.  E.g. from the image, assuming that's front and back of a single page, a horizontal cut (splitting the page vertically) would allow the top half-sheet to be flipped behind the bottom one (in the same manner as if it had been a fold), and then both (A5) half-sheets folded (a vertical fold, along the horizontal middle of the sheets), to make the final A6 booklet with, for 8 pages, 2 total A5 half-sheets from 1 initial A4 full sheet, printed on both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some simple tools for this particular problem.
First of all, if you are under linux, you should install python if it's not installed.
Any version of python will do the job.
Here's a command to install it :

```
sudo apt install python3
```

You are not done, if you read the code you will see we are using a library called numpy.
To install it, the easiest way would be through "pip"

Install pip through the following command :

```
sudo apt install pip
```

Then use pip to install numpy :

```
pip install numpy
```

Now all is left is to copy this script into a new file :

```
import numpy as np
import sys

pages = int(sys.argv[1])

pages /= 8

if (pages % 2 == 0):
    pass
else:
    pages += 1

a = np.arange(1, pages*8+1).reshape(pages, 8)

final = []

for i in a:

    t = i[0]
    i[0] = i[0]
    i[0] = t

    t = i[1]
    i[1] = i[7]
    i[7] = t

    t = i[2]
    i[2] = i[2]
    i[2] = t

    t = i[3]
    i[3] = i[5]
    i[5] = t

    t = i[4]
    i[4] = i[6]
    i[6] = t

    t = i[7]
    i[7] = i[5]
    i[5] = t

for i in a:
    for j in i:
        final.append(j)

print(final)
```

Then save as :

```
whatever.py
```

Now, to use it, open terminal and type this command :

```
python whatever.py 123
```

Notice that 123 is number of pages of your pdf.
Change it to the number of pages that you have.

The output would be a sequence of pages, like this :

```
[1, 8, 3, 6, 7, 2, 5, 4, 9, 16, 11, 14, 15, 10, 13, 12, 17, 24, 19, 22, 23, 18, 21, 20, 25, 32, 27, 30, 31, 26, 29, 28, 33, 40, 35, 38, 39, 34, 37, 36, 41, 48, 43, 46, 47, 42, 45, 44...]
```

Now all that you have left to do is to copy that sequence without the brackets : "[" , "]"

Then open your document, click "Print"
If you are using the default system print dialog
You will get something like this :

[[image: image1]]

Now choose "Pages" under "Range" and paste the sequence without brackets.

Finally, click page setup tab and choose these option :

[[image: image2]]

You can "Preview" your document to see if the page scale and sequence is correct, or just press "Print" to print it.

!! : These instructions are only valid for 8-page imposition with 2 segments of 1 sheet.

!! : I may have to turn it into a more sophisticated program, any updates will be here.

Your book will be something like :

```
-----------------          -----------------
|       |       |          |       |       |
|       |       |          |       |       |
|   1   |   2   |          |   3   |   4   |    . . .
|       |       |          |       |       |
|_______|_______|          |_______|_______|

sheet 1 - top-front         sheet 1 - top-back

-----------------          -----------------
|       |       |          |       |       |
|       |       |          |       |       |
|   5   |   6   |          |   7   |   8   |    . . .
|       |       |          |       |       |
|_______|_______|          |_______|_______|

sheet 1 - bottom-front      sheet 1 - bottom-back
```

Comment: It's great that you figured out a solution for yourself. However, this doesn't appear to do what you describe in the question, and it isn't clear how or where someone would use this script (or even what language it's in). What software would you use this with, and how would you use it? What's the process that gets you to the printed output? It looks like maybe you produce a page sequence that can be applied to something else that uses it to position the pages on each sheet, but you are still left with rotating pages, shrinking pages, duplexing, adjusting for binding and trimming, etc. (cont'd)

Comment: For a 248 page book, sequencing the pages is just the first, and easiest step in a long process.  Can you expand your answer to add the detail that would allow others with the same problem to make use of this (i.e., turn your solution into a solution)?

Comment: Give me about 12 hours and I will modify my response and make it clearer, thank you for pointing out to it ambiguity.

Comment: @fixer1234 sorry for being late. is it clear now? can you please include images?

Comment: This is a high quality answer now, but it answers a completely different question from what you asked.  Even within the answer, the sequences aren't internally consistent.  If someone lands here with a problem similar to your question, this answer will leave them scratching their head trying to understand how it solves the original question.  Changing the question at this point will invalidate the other answers.  It might be worth adding a sentence or two to this answer to explain how this addresses what you described in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party, but there are several options to accomplish what is being asked. For the sake of helping others who like me have asked themselves this question, I'm going to suggest three tools that I have tested in Manjaro Linux, but they should be easy to install and use in Ubuntu as well:

1. PDF::Imposition
2. pdfimpose
3. jPDF Tweak

---

### [PDF::Imposition](https://metacpan.org/release/PDF-Imposition)

This is a command line script, written in Perl by [Marco Pessotto](https://metacpan.org/author/MELMOTHX), with several handy options for *imposing* a document. PDF::Imposition ships with schemas that allow the user to select among several imposition layouts. For this particular question, the schema to be used is [2x4x1](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Imposition::Schema2x4x1), which was written by [Daniel Drennan ElAwar](https://metacpan.org/author/ELAWAR).

First, download and install the module from [The Comprehensive Perl Archive Network (CPAN)](https://www.cpan.org/) with the command:

```
cpan PDF::Imposition
```

Then run:

```
pdf-impose.pl --schema "2x4x1" input.pdf output.pdf
```

---

### [pdfimpose](https://framagit.org/spalax/pdfimpose)

Similar to the first option, `pdfimpose` is also a command line script. It was written in Python by [Louis Paternault](https://framagit.org/spalax) with very few dependencies. It *doesn't seem* to be as powerful as PDF::Impose, but it can do several imposition layouts.

If you are more familiar with Python than Perl, you may give it a try by downloading and installing with pip:

```
pip install pdfimpose
```

And then, running with:

```
pdfimpose --size 2x2 input.pdf --output output.pdf
```

*Disclaimer*: The result obtained differs *slightly* from what was asked as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC3BT.png).

---

### [jPDF Tweak](http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/)

jPDF Tweak is a PDF modification software that, according to its site, *can combine, split, rotate, reorder, watermark, encrypt, sign, and otherwise tweak PDF files*. It was written in Java by [Michael Schierl](https://sourceforge.net/u/schierlm/profile/) featuring a Graphical User Interface (GUI). For this particular question the Shuffle/N-up tab is going to be used. This tab provides also a layout preview, which helps *a lot* when trying to impose PDFs.

First, download and install jPDF Tweak. While it isn't in the Debian or Ubuntu repositories, there are [binaries available](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpdftweak/files/jpdftweak/jpdftweak-1.1/) for both x64 and x86 architectures. If that doesn't work, the Windows version should run fine in Wine. Another *hacky* alternative would be downloading from [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jpdftweak/), looking into the PKGBUILD and trying to reproduce the installation.

Once you have installed jPDF Tweak:

1. Select the input file [(example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1dHb.png);
2. Select the output file [(example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZghMN.png);
3. Set the following options in the *Shuffle/N-up* tab:

   - Check the *Shuffle* checkbox.
   - Select the *Booklet 2-Up Cut* preset.
   - Use the following config strin`:

   ```
   -8:!-5U0.5-100.0%-200.0%,+4U0.5-200.0%-200.0%,-8N0.5+0.0%+0.0%,+1N0.5+100.0%+0.0%,!+3U0.5-100.0%-200.0%,-6U0.5-200.0%-200.0%,+2N0.5+0.0%+0.0%,-7N0.5+100.0%+0.0%
   ```

   - Click the `Use` button to update the settings;
   - Click the `run` button to impose the PDF [(example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxyuT.png).

My only concern with jPDF Tweak is that it hasn't been updated in over 9 years, however, it works and imposes fine.

---

### Other options:

Other options which you may explore are:

- [pdfbook2](https://github.com/jenom/pdfbook2), written in Python by [Johannes Neumann](https://github.com/jenom).
- [PDF::Impose](https://github.com/jamis/impose) written in Ruby by [Jamis Buck](https://github.com/jamis).

Answer (score 1):

Generally, applications output the pages in sequence for printing one page to a sheet.  To print the output as a book or booklet requires something subsequent to modify things.

Simple conversions, like duplexing for two-sided printing or fitting two pages per sheet in the same orientation, can sometimes be done by the printer driver.  Sequencing pages into simple signatures can be handled by a number of PDF utilities (a signature is a group of pages, usually folded together in the middle, and bound as one of the sections in constructing a book).  There are also a number of web sites that will do the conversion for you for small jobs.

What you want to do isn't a built-in feature of any PDF software I'm aware of.  It requires breaking the entire document into signatures; sequencing the pages between front and back, and top and bottom, in a complicated way; laying out the pages 4-up and rotating half the pages, mixing those within a sheet; scaling the content to a reduced size; and adjusting to allow for binding, and potentially trimming, on the correct page edges.  You can do that manually, or with a script, in combination with a PDF utility.  To give you an idea of what the script would be like, see [Ubuntu - Imposition or how to print a book from your documents](http://www.bernaerts-nicolas.fr/linux/74-ubuntu/248-ubuntu-imposition-print-book), and that is just to sequence pages at half-size for signatures.  For a 248 page book, it would involve a lot of work.

There are a number of booklet printing programs, but most of them aren't designed for something this complex (and there aren't many that run in Linux).  You can investigate [PdfBooklet](http://pdfbooklet.sourceforge.net/).  I haven't used it, but it is pretty sophisticated.  As near as I can tell, it could achieve what you need, but would require some manual settings on a page-by-page basis (it allows separate settings for even and odd pages, but that won't help in this case).

When I was still using Windows, I made heavy use of an application called [ClickBook](https://www.bluesquirrel.com/products/clickbook/), which did a great job of quickly turning any document into any book or booklet format, among other things.  I think what you want to do is a built-in format.  If not, you can define the format.  It's available for Windows and Mac but not Linux, and it won't run in Wine (I tried, probably related to their DRM controls).  It's now priced at $50, although there's a free 15 day trial.  If you have just the one job, I'd get the free trial and find a Windows or Mac computer to run it on.  If you will need to regularly print in various book and booklet formats, you'll get your money's worth if you have ready access to a Windows or Mac computer.  I haven't found a Linux replacement for it.

Comment: Very helpful, even though none of the software or the article serve my purpose but your response motivated me into making a small utility for this purpose since there isn't any I'm aware of, I should stop searching and make one. I may include a github link for the finished project in this post. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way to do it (should not be hard to do yourself):

1. Extract pages into images *(e.g. pdfimages, below, others might be better choices)*
2. Composite 4 images for each sheet by use of e.g. ImageMagick/convert (use any scripting language you're comfortable with).
3. Print the images from 2)

---

```
$ pdfimages --help
pdfimages version 0.41.0
Copyright 2005-2016 The Poppler Developers - http://poppler.freedesktop.org
Copyright 1996-2011 Glyph & Cog, LLC
Usage: pdfimages [options]  
  -f        : first page to convert
  -l        : last page to convert
  -png           : change the default output format to PNG
  -tiff          : change the default output format to TIFF
  -j             : write JPEG images as JPEG files
  -jp2           : write JPEG2000 images as JP2 files
  -jbig2         : write JBIG2 images as JBIG2 files
  -ccitt         : write CCITT images as CCITT files
  -all           : equivalent to -png -tiff -j -jp2 -jbig2 -ccitt
  -list          : print list of images instead of saving
  -opw   : owner password (for encrypted files)
  -upw   : user password (for encrypted files)
  -p             : include page numbers in output file names
  -q             : don't print any messages or errors
  -v             : print copyright and version info
  -h             : print usage information
  -help          : print usage information
  --help         : print usage information
  -?             : print usage information
```

---

NOTE: The choice of QUALITY is up to you (the user); simply render LARGER images (= higher resolution, pixel count) that then are fed to the printing process.
This will allow the printing process to create higher quality prints,  ASSUMING you set IT to use a higher resolution, it must be FOLLOWING & MATCHING the images.
*(Note that pdfimages doesn't seem to have resolution -related options)*

But then; at some point the GAIN of increasing image resolution will diminish.

Memory and disk requirements will be manageable or even "low" if you render one page (or even batch) at a time.

Comment: Just a note that if one is extracting images, one potentially looses (or at least reduces) the capacity to have high-quality viewing (and/or printing) of the resultant document.  From the help you list, I don't see any information about what resolution is maintained, but even if it's very high, it probably loses something in the resulting document -- which may be irrelevant if it's used to print and then discarded, but... may not.  Probably also increases file-size substantially (ironic though that may seem).

This is still a valid answer, just pointing out potential costs.

Comment: updated with related text.